# NPC Stuck In Wrong Room

Tags: terraria-mobile

I had one house for the guide. It worked well. Then I made a new house for the merchant that came along but unfortunately the guide guy got in the new house and doesn't come out. The merchant is outside, just walking around. Instead of going into any of the houses. What should I do?

Comment: Wait a moment, if the "shop guy" is here, it means that there was a house suitable for him to come in, how many houses have you built ?

Comment: I've made two houses. One for the shop guy and one for the starter help guy. The problem is the starter help guy won't come out of the wrong one and the shop guy won't get in his room (Or the starter help guy's room, for that matter) despite the fact that he can walk over there.

Comment: @Xandawesome Hey, for archiving sake, could you tell us what Terraria are you playing? Is it mobile or standard?

Comment: I'm playing on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the second house you built may not be a proper house. You can assign houses to specific NPC's via the [housing menu](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home). This will also tell you if the house you are trying to assign is not properly built.

> The housing menu is accessed by clicking on the house icon towards the upper-right corner of the screen in the player's inventory. Selecting housing query and then clicking on a room will return a message indicating the room's status. Selecting an NPC's portrait and then clicking on a room will hang that NPC's flag somewhere in the room, thereby assigning the NPC to live in that room. NPCs can be unassigned from a room by right-clicking on their flag within the room.

Once clicked it should look like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set a home for the NPC and go mining for 30 minutes. The NPC will respawn in their House

Answer (score -2):

The door might be opened sometimes it has everything but the doors opened. (Found out myself.)